# Wolfram Alpha Text Table responses with discord.py

Tags: python, gridview, discord.py

My simple discord bot gets wolfram alpha responses for simple questions. Sometimes within these responses the API sends back results in "grid" format (still in text tho). I know how to find if a value is grid or not, but I was wondering what nice methods people have to show it in a nicer manner in a discord.py embed. An example response I get is ["plaintext":"phase at STP | gas\nmelting point | -259.14 °C (rank: 101st)\nboiling point | -252.87 °C (rank: 93rd)\n(properties at standard conditions)]

I will attach a picture of how it looks like (now) in a discord.py embed. if y'all have better ideas to help me create a nice table, it is much appreciated.[Current embed looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHhP5.png). Note that this is simple, the results might get hectic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.